# Access variable from function

Tags: javascript, jquery, scene7

I have a function that has a values inserted into variables in another function.

**Initialise**:

When the window resizes, it fires the **resizeImage()** function.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    resizeImage();
});
```

**Resize Function**:

This function checks every element with the **image-resize** class and add readjust the SRC for the image by changing the width value (dynamic from scene7).

The problem is that **element.attr('src', newSrc);** newSrc doesn't exist as its stored in **sizingMethod()**.

Is there anyway of grabbing the variable from **sizingMethod()** function and placing it within the **element.attr('src', newSrc);**.

```
function resizeImage() {
    $('.image-resize').each(function () {

        var element = $(this), src = $(this).attr('src'), regx = /wid=\d+(\.\d)*/g, currentWidth, newWidth, newSrc;

        var attrElement = $(this), attrSrc = $(this).attr('data-zoom-image'), attrRegex = /wid=\d+(\.\d)*/g, attrCurrentWidth, attrNewWidth, attrNewSrc;

        if ($(window).width() > 1824) {
            sizingMethod(src, regx, currentWidth, newWidth, newSrc, '2000');
        } else if ($(window).width() <= 1824 && $(window).width() > 1366) {
            sizingMethod(src, regx, currentWidth, newWidth, newSrc, '1824');
        }

        element.attr('src', newSrc);
    });
};
```

**Sizing Function**:

```
function sizingMethod(sSrc, sRegex, sCurrentW, sNewW, sNewSrc, sNewWidth){
    sCurrentW = sSrc.match(sRegex);
    sNewW = 'wid=' + sNewWidth;
    sNewSrc = sSrc.replace(sCurrentW, sNewW);
    textWidth = sNewW.replace('wid=', '');
    $(".dsply-screen-size").text($(window).width());
    $(".dsply-image-size").text(textWidth);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use a primitive, what you send is the value not the reference, so the sNewSrc != newSrc, so any changes you do to sNewSrc that variable will not change newSrc.

You can fix your code using:

---

**return**: returning the value in the function sizingMethod:

```
if ($(window).width() > 1824) {
    newSrc = sizingMethod(src, regx, currentWidth, newWidth, '2000');
} else if ($(window).width() <= 1824 && $(window).width() > 1366) {
    newSrc = sizingMethod(src, regx, currentWidth, newWidth, '1824');
}
```

Sizing Function:

```
function sizingMethod(sSrc, sRegex, sCurrentW, sNewW, sNewWidth){
    sCurrentW = sSrc.match(sRegex);
    sNewW = 'wid=' + sNewWidth;
    var sNewSrc = sSrc.replace(sCurrentW, sNewW);
    textWidth = sNewW.replace('wid=', '');
    $(".dsply-screen-size").text($(window).width());
    $(".dsply-image-size").text(textWidth);
    return sNewSrc;
}
```

---

**closure**: if declare sizingMethod inside the anonymous function you have access to the variable newSrc and other variables as well.

```
function resizeImage() {
    $('.image-resize').each(function () {

        var element = $(this), src = $(this).attr('src'), regx = /wid=\d+(\.\d)*/g, currentWidth, newWidth, newSrc;

        var attrElement = $(this), attrSrc = $(this).attr('data-zoom-image'), attrRegex = /wid=\d+(\.\d)*/g, attrCurrentWidth, attrNewWidth, attrNewSrc;

        if ($(window).width() > 1824) {
            sizingMethod('2000');
        } else if ($(window).width() <= 1824 && $(window).width() > 1366) {
            sizingMethod('1824');
        }

        element.attr('src', newSrc);

        function sizingMethod(sNewWidth){
            currentWidth = src.match(regx);
            var sNewW = 'wid=' + sNewWidth;
            newSrc = sSrc.replace(currentWidth, sNewW);
            textWidth = sNewW.replace('wid=', '');
            $(".dsply-screen-size").text($(window).width());
            $(".dsply-image-size").text(textWidth);
        }
    });
};
```

---

**object**: if you use an object/array instead of a primitive as an argument

```
function resizeImage() {
    $('.image-resize').each(function () {

        var element = $(this), src = $(this).attr('src'), regx = /wid=\d+(\.\d)*/g, currentWidth, newWidth, newSrc = {};

        var attrElement = $(this), attrSrc = $(this).attr('data-zoom-image'), attrRegex = /wid=\d+(\.\d)*/g, attrCurrentWidth, attrNewWidth, attrNewSrc;

        if ($(window).width() > 1824) {
            sizingMethod(src, regx, currentWidth, newWidth, newSrc, '2000');
        } else if ($(window).width() <= 1824 && $(window).width() > 1366) {
            sizingMethod(src, regx, currentWidth, newWidth, newSrc, '1824');
        }

        element.attr('src', newSrc.src);
    });
};
```

Sizing Function:

```
function sizingMethod(sSrc, sRegex, sCurrentW, sNewW, sNewSrc, sNewWidth){
    sCurrentW = sSrc.match(sRegex);
    sNewW = 'wid=' + sNewWidth;
    sNewSrc.src = sSrc.replace(sCurrentW, sNewW);
    textWidth = sNewW.replace('wid=', '');
    $(".dsply-screen-size").text($(window).width());
    $(".dsply-image-size").text(textWidth);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Used the object iteration. Worked perfectly.